# Are bitwise operations faster than a call to memcpy?

Tags: c++, performance, audio

I am messing around with audio files and learning how to extract samples for manipulations and what not. Right now I am working with .wav files exclusively and making assumptions that the header is 44 bytes and that the sample size is 16 bits.

So I wrote this bit of code that takes two char values and stores it into a 2 byte short so that I can convert it into a 32 bit float.

```
        short ss = ((0x0000 | data[i*2+1]) & 0xff) << 8;
        short fs = (0x0000 | data[i*2]) & 0xff;
        short s = fs | ss;
```

Initially I used `memcpy(&s, &data[i*2], 2)` to do so. They both achieved what I wanted to do and I was able to take the values and stream it to the output buffer and it worked.

I am wondering if performing bitwise operations is worth it rather than just a simple call to memcpy performance wise.

Comment: Create a test case. Measure the time. Decide for yourself!

Comment: What?! You want to optimize copying 2 bytes? We are talking fractions of a nanosecond here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on a variety of optimizations used when compiled and so on, memcpy will be significantly slower for such a small copy (two bytes).  There are a few ways to make this even better.  For example, you can use a union to allow the compiler to access the different halves of the memory word.

```
inline float getSamp(char *data, int i)
{
    union char_short
    {
        char d[2];
        short s;
    } sdata;
    float f;

    sdata.d[1] = data[i*2+1];
    sdata.d[0] = data[i*2];

    f = sdata.s / 32768.0f; // using 32768 because this is signed, 
                            // and the maximum negative value is -32768.
                            // This gets you a range of -1 to +0.9999695
    return f;
}
```

This approach is still not optimal because of the array indexes.

Further optimization is possible using inline (so no call is performed) and bit manipulations.  Also, dereferencing the array could save some array address calculations.  If you can endure data points to the right byte, you can even save this dereferencing.

```
inline float getSample(char *data, int i);
{
    char *d = &data[2 * i];
    short sdata = ((*d) & 0x00FF);
    d++;
    sdata |= ((*d << 8) & 0xFF00);
    return sdata / 32768.0f;
}
```

While you might be able to tweak this further, it's not worth the effort since the compiler's optimization will squeeze more out for you.

So, to answer the question - it depends.  How much memory are you moving, and how much manipulation are you doing?  Given the speed of the multicore processors these days, audio is too easy.  However, if you are using a small ARM embedded system where speed and memory size are important, then the last routine will make a big difference.

Good Luck

Comment: You have UB with `union` (read without write) and with `*d++ .. | *d` (no sequence points)...

Comment: Well, while it is potentially undefined behavior to read a value using a different member than what was written (that is, to use unions to access memory in different formats) back in C99 a Technical Corrigendum allowed memory reinterpretation via unions.  This leads to a few observations - how the compiler packs data and screw up this technique (I should have defined the packing around the union).  Also, not all compilers will set a char to 8 bits and a short to 16 bits (for example some TI DSPs have 16-bit chars).  Still, I have used this technique on a huge number of projects with success.

Comment: thank you. your explanation was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Also, my parens should have made the accesses to the addresses pointed to by d work correctly.  Still, the layout was not obvious, so I modified the code to break up the accesses from the increment.  This not only shows what the system should do, it may allow the compiler to optimize better - so thank you for pointing out my confusing usage.

Comment: Even if your implementation allows the union the expected way, you have to manage endianess (as for the `memcpy`).

Comment: >Jarod42  you have to manage endianess
That is true and something to be aware of.  Using the union technique is, in general, not very portable.  It is useful for communications systems where you are going from one type of endian to another.  However, if you do, you need to comment the code to make it obvious that you are changing endian types.  

If you want portable code and are not changing endians, then the mask, shift, and OR always works (the compiler deals with endian problems).

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely to matter, but `memcpy` will be a *lot* slower. Possibly 2 or 3 times slower. It needs a loop, with a loop count.

Comment: The size is a constant, which makes it pretty easy for the compiler to avoid the loop.